Is this guy's behaviour reasonable?
A guy at work was generally helpful and pleasant to everyone, often offering support. He had been especially close with a married woman he seemed to have a crush on—something that was obvious to everyone. After she left the firm, he shifted his attention to me, frequently helping me out. Once, he even asked me to buy him a £15 book in return for his help.
Recently, as I was about to leave, he asked for a company voucher, which I gave him, jokingly adding, "This will help fund your house-buying endeavors," since he’d been talking a lot about buying a house. After that comment, he suddenly stopped speaking to me, and I later found out from his friend that he’d been upset by what I said
I’d also mentioned to him that some senior colleagues didn’t like me and shared that I struggle with depression and anxiety. Knowing he wants to advance in the company, I wonder if all this together has influenced his view of me. Given how upset he seems now, I don’t understand why he won’t just address it with me directly. My mum told me that if he were a real friend, he would have talked to me about it rather than just cutting me off.

Side remark: in general, colleagues - even if they are helpful and nice - are not friends. They can become friends, but you should really be careful for whom you invest the effort to manage to keep those two roles in balance.

The first paragraph -- his possible past relationships -- is irrelevant for work purposes. It does not mean that his simply being collegial means he is interested in you. If anything, his asking you to buy him something to pay for advice suggests he is NOT interested in anything beyond a transactional/business relationship.

Have you tried talking to him about it? Maybe apologise for your comment? On the one hand, it sounds like an innocent enough comment, on the other hand, it can easily be received as insulting (jokes about money can easily seem patronising). The most direct way to defuse this situation and stop it from becoming a long-term issue between you is to directly confront him about it directly and as soon as possible.

I have read and re-read the post. I get the distinct and unshakeable feeling that there is more to this story.
As it stands, a single comment would generally not be grounds for the cold shoulder.
However - the workplace is a different environment. If he is still being civil when required to at Work - then that is as far as you can go in terms of professional courtesy.
Your co-workers are not required to be your friends and if something has happened to interfere with what was a previous friendship - so long as they are still able to work functionally with you - that is where it stops.

If you leave it alone, rather than reminding him of this, it may blow over. If your work is not adversely affected, that would be my recommendation.

On this same track, I am left wondering what the first paragraph is meaningfully contributing to the question. The continuation afterwards is not relating to this previous "target" of his, nor her being married or him allegedly having a crush on her.

@flater - that is a good part of why I think that there is more to the story. Seems a very odd bit of info to include.

Indeed... If this were on Interpersonal Skills SE, where it should probably be, it might end up closed for lacking detail.


Is this guy's behaviour reasonable?

Who cares? As long the behavior doesn't interfere with both of your work, it's perfectly acceptable.
You are both there to do your respective jobs to the best of your abilities. While it's certainly ok to be friendly on a personal level, it's definitely not required. In factor being "too friendly" is unprofessional if it gets to the point where personal emotions get in the way of getting your work done efficiently. Hence it's best practice to keep strong personal emotions out of the workplace.

He had been especially close with a married woman he seemed to have a crush on

That's an example of unprofessional behavior. There is nothing wrong with having a crush (as this is often outside your control anyway) but acting in a way that other people notice is not ok. This being said, it's also none of your business, so unless it interferes with your own duties, you should ignore it.


I later found out from his friend that he’d been upset by what I said

Yes, and what grounds were explained for the upset?
What have you done to clarify why he was upset about that remark?
I can only speculate that it may have seemed either like a snide or contemptuous remark about his poverty, or something off-key with your position in doling out company funds.
But the best response is just to ask.

Or just apologize -- "Hey  I think you may have taken an offhand joke more seriously than it was meant. Apologies if it was in bad taste." Leaving it at that may be safer than trying to dig into exactly what nerve you stepped on; let them decide if they want to spell it out. Meanwhile, you now know one kind of joke you might want to avoid. (I have a sardonic turn of phrase myself, and learned to suppress it at work because it was too easy to misunderstand.)
